# Typoscript: Overwrite Typoscript of an extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I try to overwrite the typoscript of the extension tx_seobasics. In the tx_seobasics setup.txt I have:

```
plugin.tx_seobasics {
    # Building the page title
    10 = TEXT
    10.data = page:tx_seo_titletag // page:title
    10.trim = 1
    10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append = TEXT
    10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.data = TSFE:tmpl|sitetitle
    10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.trim = 1
    10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.required = 1
    10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.if.isTrue = {$plugin.tx_seo.titleWrapAppendSiteTitle}
    10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.noTrimWrap = | - ||
    10.stdWrap.noTrimWrap = {$plugin.tx_seo.titleWrap}
    10.stdWrap.insertData = 1
    10.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    10.wrap = <title>|</title>
    10.append < .5

    20 < .10
    20.wrap = <meta name="title" content="|" />
}
```

Now the idea is that I can set the value for `10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.data` individual for each language.

So my first step/test was I add following typoscript in the setup.txt of my own template:

```
plugin.tx_seobasics.10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.data = page:title
```

*This works* and instead of the sitetitle that is defined in the template I get the pagetitle as sitetitle.

Now I have 2 problems:

***SOLVED* First problem:**  Overwrite `.data` with `.value`

Instead of a field I want to add a value directly in typoscript, my idea was:

```
plugin.tx_seobasics.10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.value = My own text
```

or

```
plugin.tx_seobasics.10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append = TEXT
plugin.tx_seobasics.10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.value = My own text
```

both options dont overwrite anything and it still takes the `.data  = TSFE:tmpl|sitetitle`.

So how to overwrite `.data`with `.value`?

**Second problem:** Set the value for each language separately.

My typoscript setup.txt looks like this:

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:my_template/Configuration/TypoScript/setup-ch.txt">
[global]

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
 <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:my_template/Configuration/TypoScript/setup-en.txt">
[global]
```

**Edit:** I had a mistake in my language files: I was closing 2 brackets `} }` on the same line. Never thought about it, but typoscript seems to not like that.

Comment: **Problem 2**: Does your language setup work in general? Did you set `config.sys_language_uid`, `config.language` and `config.locale_all` properly?

Comment: Yes it works and I set the properties you mention. I set some proerties for `plugin.tx_news` in the language files and it seems that they make problems. When I take them out it works. It also works when I place the new config before the `plugin.tx_news`. I will edit my question and post my language file content

Comment: @undko 2 closing brackets `} }` on the same line at the end of the language files was the problem.

Comment: Syntax errors are a pain in TypoScript :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently have no idea for the language-condition problem but for overwriting the .data you should try to empty the data first:

```
plugin.tx_seobasics.10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.data >
plugin.tx_seobasics.10.stdWrap.stdWrap.append.value = My own text
```